# gcc help page in Ubuntu

Tags: gcc

In Ubuntu, gcc is the compiler that comes with the Linux operating system.

In TurboC we have a help menu to search for documentation on syntax of functions and header files. How do I find this help option for gcc here in Ubuntu?

Comment: TurboC is an IDE which provides that type of information.  `gcc` is just the bare compiler, the one that the IDEs actually call upon to compile code.  You would need to have another IDE (for C) installed to get that kind of documentation on syntax, headers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While there are subtle differences between IDE (TurbC) and the compiler (gcc). You should still be able to access some helps for gcc:

```
 man gcc
```

will give you the nix-like manual pages.

```
gcc --help
```

will give you usage help.

If you are looking forward to learning C language instead and usage of it's inbuilt functions there are plenty of resources in the web some thing like [learn-c.org](http://www.learn-c.org/)

Hope that helps !